# Simplest way to sync arbitrary object (angular model) to firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm new to Firebase. I'm trying to build an editable TreeView using Angular, and save its contents to Firebase. Contents are stored in 'tree' model, which contains a list of nodes, and every node contains a list of its sub-nodes etc.

What is the simplest way to sync this object with FireBase?
Does simple 3-way binding do the trick (just binding my model to firebase object using .$bind method)?

Here is my code. It is currently producing an error when adding nodes:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module("myApp", ["firebase"]).
controller("TreeController", ['$scope', '$firebase', function ($scope, $firebase) {
    var treeRef = new Firebase("https://flickering-fire-x.firebaseio.com/my-tree");
    $scope.delete = function (data) {
        data.nodes = [];
    };
    $scope.add = function (data) {
        data.nodes.push({
            text: "",
            nodes: []
        });
    };
    // Is this correct: ?
    $scope.remoteTree = $firebase(treeRef);
    $scope.remoteTree.$bind($scope, "tree");
}]);
```

Html:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_item_renderer.html">
    <input type = "text" ng-model = "data.text" /> 
    <button ng-click = "add(data)" > Add node </button>
    <button ng-click="delete(data)" ng-show="data.nodes.length > 0">Delete nodes</button >
    <ul> 
        <li ng-repeat = "data in data.nodes"
    ng-include = "'tree_item_renderer.html'" ></li>
    </ul>
</script>
<body ng-app="Application" ng-controller="TreeController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Where are you setting $scope.tree? Does this code work without the firebase stuff?

Comment: In the last 2 lines of javascript (hopefully).

Comment: Yes, here's the jsfiddle without Firebase: http://jsfiddle.net/oaprograms/CR9SH/

Comment: The link to the jsFiddle doesn't appear to be working

Answer (score 0):

You try to push to **undefined** array in your add function.

To avoid this error, you must create array before using it!

```
angular.module("myApp", ["firebase"]).
controller("TreeController", ['$scope', '$firebase', function ($scope, $firebase) {
    var treeRef = new Firebase("https://flickering-fire-x.firebaseio.com/my-tree");

    data.nodes = [];

    $scope.delete = function (data) {
        data.nodes = [];
    };
    $scope.add = function (data) {
        data.nodes.push({
            text: "",
            nodes: []
        });
    };
    // Is this correct: ?
    $scope.remoteTree = $firebase(treeRef);
    $scope.remoteTree.$bind($scope, "tree");
}]);
```

This will be work

Comment: This shouldn't be the problem, data.nodes is local and already defined within html. Here is my working fiddle without using firebase: http://jsfiddle.net/oaprograms/CR9SH/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - the problem was that Firebase doesn't save empty arrays, just ignores them. So the add function should check if data.nodes is undefined:

```
$scope.add = function (data) {
    var newNode = {
            text: "",
            nodes: []
        } ;
    if(data.nodes){
        data.nodes.push(newNode);
    }else{
        data.nodes = [newNode];
    }
};
```